# Adding items (strings) from a list to a QListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pyqt5, qlistwidget

First of all, my **UI** is this:

[image]

Well! I make a "Code generator". I have a blank QListWidget, **which I want to have codes**. *These codes will making with 'Create' button*. Until now, I was **testing** the script, **seeing the codes to be printed on the terminal**. Now, **I want to see them in the QListWidget**. So, *when I click the button*, a new **code will appear to the QListWidget**. First, codes go to `Codes_list = []`  with this way:

```
class Ui_MainWindow_2_1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Codes_list = []

    def Code_maker(self):
        import random
        chars= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%&*#/\?[]{}-_"
        for x in range(self.HowMany_SpinBox.value()):
            password = ""
            for y in range(0, 10):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password += password_char
            print(password)
            self.Codes_list.append(password)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow_2_1):
    # Some code later...
    self.CreateButton.clicked.connect(self.Code_maker)
```

For example, the `Codes_list` could have these codes: `["rdt5u\&/EQ", "BJnV?zNOXn", "TnRZEMjbd6", "}?TF/hmTDF", "y9D1-Cl-Hk"]`. Now, from here, **codes should transfer to the QListWidget**... How?

> My QListWidget script is this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow_2_1(object):
    # Some code later...

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow_2_1):
        # Some code later...
        self.Codes_listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.background)
        self.Codes_listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 231, 161))
        self.Codes_listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: none;\nborder-radius: 10px;")
        self.Codes_listWidget.setObjectName("Codes_listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setWeight(50)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.Codes_listWidget.addItems(self.Codes_list)
```

I want QListWidget to update exactly when you click the 'Create' button.

The passwords on Code_maker will stay there forever.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. When should the QListWidget be updated? And if `Code_maker` is called more than once, should the list be cleared of the previous items?

Comment: @musicamante I want QListWidget to update exactly when you click the 'Create' button.

Comment: @musicamante No the passwords will stay there forever.

Comment: Then just add `self.Codes_listWidget.addItem(password)` right after `self.Codes_list.append(password)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question solved in the comments of my question! I added `self.Codes_listWidget.addItem(password)` after `self.Codes_list.append(password)`. Thanks @musicamante!!!

> The finally script is:

```
class Ui_MainWindow_2_1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Codes_list = []

    def Code_maker(self):
        import random
        chars= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%&*#/\?[]{}-_"
        for x in range(self.HowMany_SpinBox.value()):
            password = ""
            for y in range(0, 10):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password += password_char
            print(password)
            self.Codes_list.append(password)
            self.Codes_listWidget.addItem(password)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow_2_1):
    # Some code later...
    self.CreateButton.clicked.connect(self.Code_maker)
```

> My finally QListWidget script is:

```
class Ui_MainWindow_2_1(object):
    # Some code later...

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow_2_1):
        # Some code later...
        self.Codes_listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.background)
        self.Codes_listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 231, 161))
        self.Codes_listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: none;\nborder-radius: 10px;")
        self.Codes_listWidget.setObjectName("Codes_listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setWeight(50)
        item.setFont(font)
```